# openpyxl - change width of n columns

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to change the column width for n number of columns.
I am able to do this for rows as per the below code.

```
rowheight = 2
while rowheight < 601:
    ws.row_dimensions[rowheight].height = 4
    rowheight += 1
```

The problem I have is that columns are in letters and not numbers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As pointed out by ryachza the answer was to use an openpyxl utility, however the utility to use is `get_column_letter` and not `column_index_from_string` as I want to convert number to letter and not visa versa.

Here is the working code

```
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

# Start changing width from column C onwards
column = 3
while column < 601:
    i = get_column_letter(column)
    ws.column_dimensions[i].width = 4
    column += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the column index, you should be able to use:

```
i = openpyxl.utils.column_index_from_string(?)
```

And then:

```
ws.column_dimensions[i].width = ?
```

Comment: You can also group columns to do this in a single assignment, though we're still not sure exactly how column grouping is supposed to work.

Comment: Hi Charlie, I would be interested in seeing an example of doing this by grouping columns.